# How to hide content when first displaying the view (Views contextual filter)

Tags: views, nodes

I am on drupal 7.56 and using **Views** to display some content based on a **filter**.

**I am trying to not display content when the user opens the page for the first time**. I want to make sure the user only displays values that will be related to the filter. My filter is on the Title and is a Search box.

I know that it is possible to reach that goal with contextual filter. I did it once, but can't do it again.

Can somebody help me make that views work like that ?

Comment: `I am on drupal 7.56` I hope this is just for development, there was a big security update on 7.57.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an exposed filter and selecting the input required option. This option will appear in the Advanced section in the view configuration. You'll want to add an exposed filter for your title field first. *I think* that's in core.

Comment: OK. Thanks I'll try it first (Required) and give a feedback.

Comment: Thanks **@sonfd**. It's all I needed. Sometimes things are very **simple** and we just do not see. I Just make the exposed filter **required** and now nothing shows before a recognized value is sent.